# How to use positional Placeholder in yii2 Yii:t();

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to use named placeholder in Yii:t(); but  when i translate the message i get error

```
@MISSING: app . Hi, sam! FOR LANGUAGE zh-CN @
```

this is my view file

```
<?=\Yii::t('app', 'Hi, {username}!', [
          'username' => \Yii::$app->user->identity->username,
   ]);?>
```

in  my `app.php` file i have the key as `'Hi' => '你好',` i also try added the comma after the hi like this `'HI,' => '你好',`  but none of this work for me how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have complete phrase in your translation file (`app.php`), including placeholder:

```
return [
    'Hi, {username}!' => '你好, {username}!',
];
```